# Seeking font recommendations

Tags: fonts

Looking to find some interesting fonts for an investment research product, mostly distributed in PDF form.

This is a somewhat dry use case —- high volume dense content at small point sizes for a niche professional audience, and legibility is the main goal. But would like something a bit more distinctive than the standard system fonts.

For the body text I've already licensed the Equity font from [MB Type](https://www.mbtype.com), which is really growing on me... so I'm open to other suggestions there, but particularly curious for other sans / tabular options.

See current dummy page attached. Thanks in advance for any suggestions!

[image: sample page]

Comment: Recommending fonts is always a pleasure. To narrow it down it might be helpful to know what kind of things you're looking for, so if there are any fonts that are pretty close to what you want but not quite.

Answer (score 5):

My general recommendation in choosing typefaces is twofold:

1. Limit yourself to two typefaces<sup>*</sup> in a single work. Only use a third if it's a display type for a title or streamer.
2. Don't choose two typefaces that belong to the same general category (Classic serif / Newtype Serif / Slab Serif / Sans Serif / Display Type) unless they are strikingly different to the layperson's eye.

<sup>*</sup> <sub>A 'typeface' contains multiple fonts. Arial is a typeface, Arial extra bold is a font. You can use multiple fonts in a work, while still using only a single typeface.</sub>

You combine three typefaces (Fire, Calibri and Equity), two of which are sans serifs. Try and reduce this to two. Laypeople may not see the difference between the to sans typefaces, but will unconsciously start doubting whether they are looking at the same typeface or not.

Also, I really, really recommend avoiding Calibri, as it look very amateur to say it in the most gentle way I can think of. Because Calibri is the standard in MS Office, every random schmuck who starts writing a letter, uses Calibri. The typeface screams 'standard' and 'trite' only slightly less loudly than Times New Roman does.

What's wrong with Fira regular for the table contents? It seems perfectly legible to me.

Comment: Thanks Vincent! You have helped me to narrow down the question. This may also explain why designers see more Calibri than they would like in the business world:

1. No OpenType support in Excel, so I'm limited to fonts that have tabular and lining figures by default... which seems to exclude Fira Sans and many others

2. Impractical to reformat tables in a different font every time we bring them into Word

3. By following your rule #1, I am limited to the Excel font for the whole doc. 

So maybe Q is what are the best Excel friendly Calibri alternatives…?

Comment: @Peter You are touching on the reason why I almost always choose to re-create tables in InDesign for publication, rather than paste in the Excel versions. Thank Adobe for allowing for relatively smooth copy-pasting of table content. The question you phrase at the end of your comment would be a separate question altogether, that I'd recommend you post as, well, a new question :)

Comment: you're right, just posted it [here](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/155021/what-are-the-best-excel-friendly-fonts)

Comment: One minor addendum to the fonts rule 1 (the "Coco Channel Typeface Corollary" we all were taught in design class): don't double emphasize. For the block quote, I see a font change and italics. Try leaving it Equity Italic, and rely on white space (indent, leading) to highlight its block-quotedness. This reduces your issue to just Calibri in the tables. An easier "offense." I happen to think Calibri is perfectly cromulent but Vincent is right: using it can be inferred as laziness.

Comment: @Yorik I learned the meaning of the word 'cromulent' today ^^.

Answer (score 2):

Have you checked out [Google Fonts](https://fonts.google.com/)? They have a lot of attractive fonts, most with no license restrictions. Many have multiple weights, which could help with things like your table – one easy way to avoid combining different typefaces is by using a bold for the section head, semi-bold for column/row titles, and regular or light one for the main data.

Roboto is the most popular Sans Serif typeface there, but there are many other good-looking options that are not too flashy for investment research products.