# What are the best Excel-friendly fonts?

Tags: fonts

As with most system fonts, the design world seems quite negative on Calibri. And I get it, but many of the recommended alternatives are impractical for those of us that need to produce a lot of content in Excel, at a pace that makes it impossible to redo every table in another app.

So can anyone recommend other sans options that

1. work at small point sizes for
2. dense, tabular, mostly numeric content,
3. both on screen and in print, and
4. have tabular and lining figures turned on **by default**

The last one is critical (since Excel does not support OpenType options) and I don't even know how to filter for it at foundry/catalog websites.

Thanks in advance for any suggestions!

Comment: Calibri **is** installed with Office though. If the goal is to have files transferable between systems, I've found it's **always** wise to just stick with the defaults whatever the Microsoft app wants to use. The more you customize fonts, the **less** transferable files are between systems/users. MS is pretty horrible at maintaining custom font choices. It's not about "Excel friendly" it's about "what won't the MS app mess up".

Comment: @Scott Agreed, but sometimes I don't need the files to be transferable between systems or users.

Comment: So to be clear you are asking for the use-case of pre-baked presentation (not inter-operability); you need fonts where lining *and* tabular numerals are the *default* set (like Calibri); cannot be Type1 (no Office support)

Comment: @Scott - My bad. I have it, but it's deactivated.

Comment: @Tetsujin I deactivate it too.. and it gets auto-activated whenever I launch an MS app `:)` I don't use it anywhere else.

Comment: @Scott - just tested. Excel *thinks* I'm typing in Calibri, but it's still not activated in FontExplorer & copy/paste tells me it's actually Helvetica. [/me jumps up & down like a small child, crying 'Ya boo sucks, Microsoft. You lose"] [sorry]

Comment: Yeah.. MS can be pretty horrible `:)`

Comment: @Yorik Correct, except that I'm not sure what you mean by "pre-baked presentation." I included a sample use case in my [previous question](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/155009/seeking-font-recommendations) but trying to narrow it down here to the core problem

Comment: By "pre-baked" I just meant so-called closed or uneditable formats (PDF; screencapture; slide presentation) where the font face is embedded or otherwise rendered and portable instead of reliant on the current system for display.

Comment: @Tetsujin That sincerely made me lol, thanks XD

Answer (score 1):

Definitely recommend Hoefler/Monotype's [Office Fonts](https://www.typography.com/blog/office-fonts). Among other things, they're tweaked so the space between lines is quite narrow and the x-height quite high, so they'll feel right in charts.